# Inyectar un fragment/interfaz con hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger, hilt

Tengo un `fragmentA` el cual implementa una `interfaceA`.

Ya me hice el correspondiente `module` para proveer el `fragment` correspondiente

```
@Module
@InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)
class FragmentModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideInterfaceA(fragment: Fragment): InterfaceA =
        fragment as InterfaceA
}
```

El problema es que hilt quiere castear un `fragment` que no implementa dicha interfaz y obtengo un `ClassCastException`.

La estructura de mis views es mas o menos asi

```
<activity>
   <navHostFragment/> //este es mi mainNavhostFragment y mi fragmentA
</activity>

//fragmentA
<constraintlayout>
    <navhostFragment/> //otro navhost que se maneja con un bottom navigation, aca se maneja un fragmentTab1 y fragmentTab2
    <BottomNavigation/>
</constraintlayout>
```

y cuando se crea el view de `fragmentTab1`, me dice que no implementa `interfaceA`

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class fragmentTab1 : Fragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var interfaceA: InterfaceA
```

- ¿Hay alguna forma de indicarle a `hilt` que si el fragment no implementa la interface no intente hacer el cast?
- O ¿cómo tendría que ser la configuración para que mi `fragmentA` se inyecte de manera adecuada?

Comment: Considera aplicar para esto Arquitectura limpia (Clean Architecture), cuando puedes lee sobre el tema, porque Android apunta a eso, además, con Hilt es sumamente fácil inyectar módulos o proveer recursos donde lo necesites de forma limpia. Puedes empezar implementando el patrón MVVM por ejemplo, que te ayudará a comprender Clean Architecture y escribir aplicaciones que aseguren un manejo correcto del ciclo de vida y fáciles de manetener. Otros elementos interesantes son el Componente de Navegación y DataBinding, que facilitan tareas como lo que quieres hacer aquí...

Comment: ... todo lo mencionado antes, y otras cosas más, Android lo ha agrupado en algo que se llama [Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack). Es un avance enorme en muchos aspectos, habrá una curva de aprendizaje, pero, si revisas los [ejemplos de Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose), facilitará bastante la forma de programar y sobre todo de hacer cosas complejas.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya ando usando mvvm, databinding, viewmodel y jetpack en general. Aun asi, como ejecutas una accion (propia de la vista) desde una tab (en mi ejemplo fragmentTab1) pero que la accion se encuentra en el fragmentA? mi segunda opcion es usar un sharedviewmodel con el activity y hacer los observes necesarios. Para eso hice que mi fragmentA implemente una interface y la queria inyectar

Comment: Ummm no sé, si es para pasar datos entre Fragmentos no veo en qué deba intervenir Hilt aquí, ni siquiera el ViewModel o el Repository, simplemente pasa los datos usando Componentes de Navegación o usando Extras no sé. Ambos fragmentos están en el contexto de la Vista, no tienes que meterte en historias de inyectar o de interfaces y demás.

Comment: Mira este ejemplo (es en Java): `v.setOnClickListener(v1 -> {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("bookId", mItem.getId());
                Navigation.findNavController(v1).navigate(R.id.nav_libros, bundle);` ahí yo navego hacia un fragmento, en el segundo parámetro de `navigate` paso un Bundle con un dato **dinámico** tomado de un RecyclerView. Ese código está en el Adapter del RecyclerView.

Comment: @A.Cedano no estan en el mismo lugar, uno es un fragment que es un tab y el otro es el contenedor de ese tab (tecnicamente el parent fragment). Si puedo hacer un findnavcontroller y poner el fragment que quiero, pero por requerimientos, la navegacion se debe hacer desde el fragmentA (por un shared element transition de unos comopnentes que estan en el fragmentA y esa es la accion que esta dentro de mi interfaceA , la navegacion) y no se debe hacer desde mi fragmentTab (por que no puedo acceder a los elementos compartidos desde mi fragmentTab)

Comment: ¿Cuando dices que no están en el mismo lugar te refieres a que están en **módulos distintos** (un fragmento en una Aplicación A por ejemplo y otro en una Aplicación F)? Eso sería lo único que justificaría aquí la inyección de dependencias (para inyectar entre módulos) y usando otra forma para pasar datos. Pero si están en el mismo módulo (por ejemplo, todos los fragments de tu aplicación) no haria falta inyección de dependencias para esto, pues ambos fragmentos **están en el contexto de la vista** y con las herramientas de Android puedes comunicar entre ellos sin mayores complicaciones.

Comment: @A.Cedano si estan en el mismo modulo. Lo que no se puede hacer es acceder a la navegacion desde el fragment hijo (fragmentTab1), pero realizandola con un shared element transition de componentes que tiene el fragmentA. O bueno, tecnicamente si puedo acceder a la navegacion desde el fragmentTab1, pero no podria hacer la shared element transition, por que para hacerla se tiene que hacer desde el fragmentA

Comment: [Según la doc, debes usar `@Binds` para inyectar instancias de interfaces](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android?hl=es-419#inject-interfaces).

Comment: @A.Cedano si lo se, eso ayuda a reducir tiempos de compilacion y a tener tus modulos un poco mas bonitos, pero nada impediria que use provides

Answer (score 0):

El detalle en general, es que, no estás especificando que Fragment debe usar Hilt aquí:

```
@Provides
fun provideInterfaceA(fragment: Fragment /*Este Fragment*/): InterfaceA =
    fragment as InterfaceA
```

Entonces Hilt provee uno por defecto que no es el que tu requieres.

Puedes intentar especificar que fragment debe utilizar (aunque no estoy seguro que eso sea posible) usando los `qualifiers` de Hilt. Más info: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android?hl=es-419#multiple-bindings

Ahora, posiblemente debas cambiar tu implementación, en lugar de usar un fragment, usar un `UseCase` o un `Repository`, que sea inyectable en tu fragment (y preferiblemente a tu ViewModel).

De esa manera es más sencillo inyectar las dependencias sin tener que recurrir al `casting` de clases.

Comment: es que realmente el fragmentA se tiene que mover a un fragmentB, pero no puedo acceder desde mi fragmentTab al componente de navegacion del fragmentA, entonces hice una interfaceA que ejecute la navegacion. Simplifique un poco el escenario por que mi interfaceA la mandaria a un adapter para un evento de clicklistener dentro de un recycler

Comment: Basado en tu requerimiento, probablemente debas utilizar otro enfoque, podría tener algunos inconvenientes con fugas de memoria, o problemas que irían creciendo si la aplicación necesita añadir nuevas características.

Una de las propuestas es usar `Flow` en tus ViewModels, ellos se comunicaran entre fragments especificando las acciones a realizar entre ellos.

Comment: si, ahorita mi "otra idea" es un shared viewmodel donde meta single live events (o lo que necesite xD) para ir notificando eventos y hacer los observes necesarios donde se requiera